# Scroll inside div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I wrote something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/yYJ3z/10/.

I have `<div>` (last block on jsfiddle) with `overflow-y: scroll`.

And scroll event:

```
$(window).on('onmousewheel', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (wheel) {
            wheel = false;
            var goingUp = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ? false : true;
            if (activeSection === 0 && goingUp) {
                wheel = true;
                return;
            }
            activeSection = goingUp ? (activeSection - 1) : (activeSection + 1);
            if (activeSection == $('.section').length) {
                activeSection = $('.section').length - 1;
            }
            scrollMeToSection();
            setTimeout(function () {
                wheel = true;
            }, 1000);
        }
});
```

If we will disable scroll event, then we scroll content inside div. If it's enabled, we can't.

How to activate scroll event in the last block. If we are watching on first or second block, we can scroll full page (block), and if on last div, we can't scroll full page until **scrollbar** inside this div would be at bottom or top borders.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve with the code on `onmousewheel` ? . if u comment out `event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();` this will work.

Comment: @Khaleel - Without this `event.preventDefault();` scrolling gets jerky. `preventDefault` added smooth scroll